# PHP Session Variables Lost Despite Consistent Session ID

Tags: php, session-variables

Looking everywhere for an answer to this but no luck so far.

I've simplified my code as follows (running File 1 then File 2):

File 1

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
$_SESSION[123][123] = 'Testing';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>
```

File 2

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>
```

The output from File 1 is the session ID and correctly showing the new session variable.

The output from File 2 is the same session ID but empty session variables.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using and which are your environment specifications?

Comment: set a session_write_close(); as last command in file 1 and you have a notice in your error.log :PHP Notice:  session_write_close(): Skipping numeric key 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP variables cannot start with a number or any special character (except `_`). Hence, *$_SESSION[123] or $_SESSION["123"]* are all *invalid*

For the second part, to accept a 2D array in sessions, you have to do this

```
$some_array = array('123' => 'Testing');
$_SESSION['some_common_variable_name'] = $some_array;
```

Comment: You're spot on, my first file showed me this so I assumed it had saved:
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [123] => Testing
        )
)

Comment: Yes. I believe PHP Session treats the variables as a string somehow